# Linux wc command

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

How can i count characters, words and lines from a file with wc command?

Comment: does `wc --help` not work?

Comment: Try: `man wc`  .

Comment: look at the `man wc` page. or `info wc` page

Answer (score 5):

Lines: `wc -l filename.txt`

Characters: `wc -m filename.txt`

Words: `wc -w filename.txt`

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uwc.htm

Answer (score 1):

Wc command prints newline, word, and byte counts for each FILE, and a total line, if more than one FILE is specified.

**Syntax**

```
wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...
wc [OPTION]... --files0-from=F
```

**Option**

```
-c:- print the byte counts
-m:- print the character counts
-l:- print the newline counts
-L:- print the length of the longest line
-W:- print the word counts
–help:- Print help
–version:- Display version information
```

You can use wc command as shown below to get the required information.

Use -m option to get the Character count

```
wc -m test_file.txt
```

-w option to print words count

```
wc -w test_file.txt
```

-l option to print newline count

```
wc -l test_file.txt
```

**Note:-** wc works on “/n” lines character. It counts the newline not the number of lines. The count will be one less is there is no newline character. Refer [Why does wc -l tell me that this non-empty file has 0 lines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83408/why-does-wc-l-tell-me-that-this-non-empty-file-has-0-lines)

I hope I answered your question.